# C# calling a DLL function that returns a pointer to pointer to an array of structures

Tags: c#, c++, marshalling, dllimport, unmanaged-memory

I have tried many different combinations of the various methods to marshal this call.  This is a DLL that returns a pointer to a pointer to an array of structures.  The types like debugPort are actually enums.

```
/**
* \struct debugConnectParameters 
* \brief Get device characterization and specify connection parameters through ST-LINK interface. 
*/ 
typedef struct debugConnectParameters { 
    debugPort dbgPort;        /**< Select the type of debug interface #debugPort. */ 
    int index;                /**< Select one of the debug ports connected. */ 
    char serialNumber[33];    /**< ST-LINK serial number. */ 
    char firmwareVersion[20]; /**< Firmware version. */ 
    char targetVoltage[5];    /**< Operate voltage. */ 
    int accessPortNumber;     /**< Number of available access port. */ 
    int accessPort;           /**< Select access port controller. */ 
    debugConnectMode connectionMode; /**< Select the debug CONNECT mode #debugConnectMode. */ 
    debugResetMode resetMode; /**< Select the debug RESET mode #debugResetMode. */ 
    int isOldFirmware;        /**< Check Old ST-LINK firmware version. */ 
    frequencies freq;         /**< Supported frequencies #frequencies. */ 
    int frequency;            /**< Select specific frequency. */ 
    int isBridge;             /**< Indicates if it's Bridge device or not. */ 
    int shared;               /**< Select connection type, if it's shared, use ST-LINK Server. */ 
} debugConnectParameters;

int getStLinkList(debugConnectParameters** stLinkList, int shared);
```

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public unsafe struct debugConnectParameters
    {
        debugPort dbgPort;                  /**< Select the type of debug interface #debugPort. */
        int index;                          /**< Select one of the debug ports connected. */
        fixed char serialNumber[33];        /**< ST-LINK serial number. */
        fixed char firmwareVersion[20];     /**< Firmware version. */
        fixed char targetVoltage[5];        /**< Operate voltage. */
        int accessPortNumber;               /**< Number of available access port. */
        int accessPort;                     /**< Select access port controller. */
        debugConnectMode connectionMode;    /**< Select the debug CONNECT mode #debugConnectMode. */
        debugResetMode resetMode;           /**< Select the debug RESET mode #debugResetMode. */
        int isOldFirmware;                  /**< Check Old ST-LINK firmware version. */
        frequencies freq;                   /**< Supported frequencies #frequencies. */
        int frequency;                      /**< Select specific frequency. */
        int isBridge;                       /**< Indicates if it's Bridge device or not. */
        int shared;                         /**< Select connection type, if it's shared, use ST-LINK Server. */
    }
    [DllImport(dllPath + "CubeProgrammer_API.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public unsafe extern static int getStLinkList(
        debugConnectParameters** stLinkList,
        int shared
        );
```

I have tried replacing the using "out" and "ref" options.  I have tried to find a version of IntPtr that it likes.  I keep getting: System.AccessViolationException.  I have contacted STMicroelectronics about how to interface with this DLL, but so far they have been no help.  The rest of the calls in the DLL are pretty simple but I must have this one working to get started, since it is the information about what JTAG device is actually connected.

Updated (6/12/20) to add the actual calling function and now the calling function copies the structures from unmanaged to managed structures.  But the call to getStLinkList() still does not work.

```
        public unsafe static int GetDeviceList(ref debugConnectParameters[] debugParams, int maxCount)
        {
            IntPtr unManagedListPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(debugConnectParameters*));
            IntPtr *unManagedListPtrPtr = &unManagedListPtr;
            int count = getStLinkList((debugConnectParameters**)unManagedListPtrPtr, 0);
            IntPtr copyPtr = unManagedListPtr;
            if (count > maxCount) count = maxCount;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                debugParams[i] = (debugConnectParameters)Marshal.PtrToStructure(copyPtr, typeof(debugConnectParameters));
                copyPtr += sizeof(debugConnectParameters);
            }
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(unManagedListPtr);
            return (count);
        }
```

I also tried these changes with no luck.  I am still seeing access violations.  Attempt to read or write protected memory.

```
    [DllImport(dllPath + "CubeProgrammer_API.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        unsafe private static extern int getStLinkList(
            ref IntPtr stLinkList,
            int shared
            );
    unsafe public static int GetDeviceList(List<debugConnectParameters> list)
    {
        IntPtr unManagedListPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(debugConnectParameters*));
        IntPtr copyPtr = unManagedListPtr;

            int count = getStLinkList(ref unManagedListPtr, 0);

            if (count > 10) count = 10;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                debugConnectParameters parameter = (debugConnectParameters)Marshal.PtrToStructure(copyPtr, typeof(debugConnectParameters));
                list.Add(parameter);
                copyPtr += sizeof(debugConnectParameters);
            }

            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(unManagedListPtr);
            return (count);
    }
```

Comment: Hold on, you're getting access violation with only a `ref IntPtr`? That has nothing to do with marshalling, that's a bugged library implementation. Indeed, I googled a bit about your library and plenty of people are having trouble working with it just in plain C++. I suggest you dump it and use something better.

Comment: Just for completeness' sake, you are misusing the marshaller, most of your code can be done automatically (`string` instead of `fixed char[]`, arrays instead of pointers, etc etc).

Comment: It is very hard to get rid of the library that is the interface to the USB device that you are using to program a custom board.  As to the fixed char,  those are fixed length arrays of ASCII characters.

Comment: I know what they are, I'm telling you there is a better and simpler way to do that in C#.

Comment: Can you look on my post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75146690/how-to-passing-variables-from-c-to-vb-net

Answer (score 6):

There are a two things working against us in regards to calling the `getStLinkList` function of the "CubeProgrammer_API.dll" library in particular. Without correcting them the library will not work, even from C++.

First, the dependencies for that library found in the *api/lib* folder of the STM32CubeProgrammer installation are not all compiled for x64. The versions in the *bin* folder are and those are the libraries you'll want to have available at runtime. I've done this by setting the working directory to that directory in the project Debug settings. This was verified by checking the target machine of each DLL in the *api/lib* and *bin* folders.

Second, the "CubeProgrammer_API.dll" needs to be initialized before calling `getStLinkList` by calling the `setLoadersPath` and `setDisplayCallbacks` functions. The first function must be provided the path to the "Flash Loader", which is *bin/FlashLoader* in my case. The `setDisplayCallbacks` function takes a structure of three function pointers.

The example below might not be the best example of type marshaling, but it will illustrate the process.

```cs
public static class CubeProgrammerApi
{
    public enum DebugConnectionMode
    {
        NormalMode = 0,
        HotplugMode = 1,
        UnderResetMode = 2,
        PreResetMode = 3
    }
    
    public enum DebugResetMode
    {
        SoftwareReset = 0,
        HardwareReset = 1,
        CoreReset = 2
    }
    
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class Frequencies
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 12)]
        uint[] JtagFrequency;
        uint JTagFrequencyNumber;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 12)]
        uint[] SwdFrequency;
        uint SwdFrequencyNumber;
    }
    
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public class DebugConnectParameters
    {
        DebugPort DebugPort;
        public int Index;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 33)]
        public string SerialNumber;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 20)]
        public string FirmwareVersion;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 5)]
        public string TargetVoltage;
        public int AccesPortNumber;
        public int AccessPort;
        public DebugConnectionMode connectionMode;
        public DebugResetMode resetMode;
        public bool IsOldFirmware;
        public Frequencies Freqencies;
        public int Frequency;
        public bool IsBridge;
        public int Shared;
    }
    
    public delegate void LogMessageReceived(int messageType, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string message);
    public delegate void InitProgressBar();
    public delegate void ProgressBarUpdateReceived(int currentProgress, int total);

    internal static class NativeMethods
    {
        public struct DisplayCallbacks
        {
            public InitProgressBar initProgressBar;
            public LogMessageReceived logMessage;
            public ProgressBarUpdateReceived loadBar;
        }

        [DllImport("CubeProgrammer_API.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "setLoadersPath")]
        internal static extern void SetLoadersPath(string path);

        [DllImport("CubeProgrammer_API.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "setDisplayCallbacks")]
        internal static extern void SetDisplayCallbacks(ref DisplayCallbacks callbacks);

        [DllImport("CubeProgrammer_API.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "getStLinkList")]
        internal static extern int GetStLinkList(IntPtr stLinkList, uint shared);

        [DllImport("CubeProgrammer_API.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        internal static extern void deleteInterfaceList();

        [DllImport("CubeProgrammer_API.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "reset")]
        internal static extern int Reset([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] DebugResetMode rstMode);
    }

    public static void SetLoadersPath(string path)
    {
        NativeMethods.SetLoadersPath(path);
    }

    public static void SetDisplayCallbacks(InitProgressBar initProgressBar, LogMessageReceived messageReceived, ProgressBarUpdateReceived progressBarUpdate)
    {
        NativeMethods.DisplayCallbacks callbacksHandle;

        callbacksHandle.initProgressBar = initProgressBar;
        callbacksHandle.logMessage = messageReceived;
        callbacksHandle.loadBar = progressBarUpdate;

        NativeMethods.SetDisplayCallbacks(ref callbacksHandle);
    }

    public static IList<DebugConnectParameters> GetStLinkProgrammers(bool shared = false)
    {
        var listPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf<IntPtr>());
        var parametersList = new List<DebugConnectParameters>();

        try
        {
            var size = Marshal.SizeOf<DebugConnectParameters>();
            var numberOfItems = NativeMethods.GetStLinkList(listPtr, shared ? 1U : 0U);
            var listDereference = Marshal.PtrToStructure<IntPtr>(listPtr);

            for (var i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++)
            {
                var currentItem = Marshal.PtrToStructure<DebugConnectParameters>(listDereference + (i * size));

                parametersList.Add(currentItem);
            }

            NativeMethods.deleteInterfaceList();
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.FreeHGlobal(listPtr);
        }

        return parametersList;
    }

    public static void FreeStLinkProgrammers()
    {
        NativeMethods.deleteInterfaceList();
    }
}
```

And main:

```cs
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CubeProgrammerApi.SetLoadersPath(@"C:\Program Files\STMicroelectronics\STM32Cube\STM32CubeProgrammer\bin\FlashLoader");
            CubeProgrammerApi.SetDisplayCallbacks(InitProgressBar, ReceiveMessage, ProgressBarUpdate);
            var stLinkList = CubeProgrammerApi.GetStLinkProgrammers();

            foreach (var stlink in stLinkList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", stlink.Index, stlink.SerialNumber);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to exit");
            Console.ReadLine();

            CubeProgrammerApi.FreeStLinkProgrammers();
        }

        static void ReceiveMessage(int messgaeType, string message)
        {

        }

        static void InitProgressBar()
        {

        }

        static void ProgressBarUpdate(int currentProgress, int total)
        {

        }
    }
```

This will output the following with two debuggers attached, a STLink V3 and an STLink V2 respectively. This should get you far enough along to discover the correct types to use.

```
0 002F001D3038511834333935
1 34FF6D065250343847110943
Press ENTER to exit
```

Comment: Wow, thanks!  I will try these changes later today.

Comment: @alienbike Did this work for you? If not, please comment and I'll see what I can do to help.

Comment: I have been trying to prove that using cheap potentiometers is never a good idea.  I hope to get back on this soon.  I will update the comments after I have tried it.

Comment: @JDScott, how did you know that  setLoadersPath() and setDisplayCallbacks() need to be called before getStLinkList(). The STM32CubeProgrammer_API.chm isn't very clear about that.

Comment: @JimFred It's not obvious and I can't find a reference in the documentation to those calls being required before using the library. I discovered the problem by first trying to create a C++ project that worked correctly to prove that the Cube library worked at all. I think I was getting a nullptr exception. After looking at the example code in "[...]/STM32Cube/STM32CubeProgrammer/api/src/main.cpp", I noticed it was making those calls. After adding those calls to my code, voila. The display callbacks may be the only requirement before using the library, but I never took the time to confirm.

Comment: Also, @JimFred Could you let me know if you also get it working? Some confirmation for my sake would be nice. I know it works for me, but I don't know if I've helped anyone else achieve their goals.

Comment: @JDScott, got it working and created a Python wrapper that automatically does some of the necessary initialization. See https://github.com/jimfred/PyCubeProgrammer_API