# how to use a dll library built in vs2013 in code built in vs2017?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2017

In my work we have a version of code functions built in vs 2013 and I should build a new web based interface to the project which uses this functions.
I built the interface by using asp.net framework and vs 2017 the interface should uses this function through `dll` libraries built in vs 2013.
when I do that I got a lot of errors, so i wonder if it possible to use old version `dll` library built and depended on vs 2013 and ,of course, other toolset and `sdk` in my interface app ?

Comment: You use a VS 2017 C# interface with VS 2013 C++ dll ? If it is the case you should look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62331489/c-sharp-calling-a-dll-function-that-returns-a-pointer-to-pointer-to-an-array-of)

Comment: i meant an app to interface to these core function not an c interface